# Integrate HTML-Code from other classes to own WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a new Plugin in wordpress. My classes:

the plugin PHP-file:

```
<?php
/*
plugin-header (working)
 */

// Exit if accessed directly
defined('ABSPATH' || exit());

// Include classes
include('foo.php');
include('boo.php');

//add Init Hook
add_action('admin_menu','bohoo_admin');

function bohoo_admin() {
    add_options_page('bohoo', 'someTitle', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'createView');    
}

function createView() {
    $foo = new foo();
    $boo = new boo();

    return $foo->createFooDiv() . $boo->createBooDiv();

}

?>
```

My foo.php:

```
<?php

class foo {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function createFooDiv() {
        return '<div><h2>Hi</h2></div>';
    }

}

?>
```

My boo.php:

```
<?php

class boo {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function createBooDiv() {
        return '<div> test </div>';
    }

}


?>
```

Now what I basically tried is: The HTML-code should be in two different files and these should be concatenated and displayed (of course).

The way I understood integrating plugins in WP:

With the `add_options_page`-method you specify where your plugin is shown and what code is displayed. For the code you use the last argument (in this case the `createView`-method. This works so far if my `createView()` in my plugin PHP-file looks like this:

```
function createView() {
//include HTML-Code directly
?>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
<?php
}
?>
```

What happens when I include the `boo.php` and `foo.php` files instead of including the HTML-Code directly is nothing (So nothing is displayed and there is on error aswell). I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I also tried playing around with the HTML-Code in the return-statements of `BOO` and `FOO`, but that did not help either. What am I doing wrong? Or is it simply not possible to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print/echo your html content. Change createView to this:

```
function createView() {
    $foo = new foo();
    $boo = new boo();

    echo $foo->createFooDiv() . $boo->createBooDiv();
}
```

That's how it's done in the [add_options docs page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page).

And basically when you use php closing and opening tags:

```
?>
<h1>Some html</h1>
<?php
```

It's equivalent to printing the content in between:

```
echo '<h1>Some html</h1>';
```